# How to make emacs stop trapping Scroll Lock?

Tags: linux, emacs, scroll-lock

I am using a Linux machine with a KVM switch at work, and I commonly use emacs while switching between that machine and my other machine. I typically use the keyboard shortcut to swap between machines on the KVM, which is the key sequence: <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>. If I have an emacs window on top on Linux and hit these buttons, it will trap the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key presses and trigger a system beep from the CPU speaker. The KVM still switches, but on occasion, after the switch, it will register <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> as being stuck pressed, and so I'll be treated to an earful of system beeping. I have to switch back to the computer to get it to stop.

Is there something I can put in the .emacs file that will prevent the program from beeping when I hit <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> with the window on top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like what you're looking for [here](http://shallowsky.com/blog/tags/kvm/)

either this

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<Scroll_Lock>") 'ignore)
```

or this

```
(global-set-key [scroll-lock] 'ignore)
```

Depending on the version of emacs

Comment: Wow, I tried doing a web search but came up dry. That's incredibly specific to my situation. Thanks! I'll try it at work tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Neither of those keybindings worked, so I used the method described in the FAQ here to find it: http://xahlee.org/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html. I had to use the first form that you listed, but substitute `<Scroll_Lock>` with `<key-20>`. But now it is properly ignored! Thanks!